# Circumvent this credentials validator

Tags: javascript, programming-puzzle

This is a program I wrote in JavaScript to validate some inputted credentials, with an intentional vulnerability. The `credentials_validator` function takes an object as input, with usernames and passwords. It returns a function, which takes a username and password and returns `true` if the credentials are valid.

Your challenge is to find a `username` and `password` which, when passed to the function returned by `credentials_validator`, cause it to return `true` without knowledge of the credentials ahead of time.

This is a [programming-puzzle](/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle), so the first valid answer wins.

**Program:**

```js
var credentials_validator = (credentials) => {
    if (typeof credentials !== "object")
        throw new TypeError("'credentials' must be an object");
    
    for (var username in credentials)
        if (typeof credentials[username] === "object")
            throw new TypeError("Passwords may not be objects or 'null'");
    
    return (username, password) => {
        if (typeof password === "object")
            throw new TypeError("Passwords may not be objects or 'null'");
        
        if (!(username in credentials))
            return false;
        
        if (credentials[username] === password)
            return true;
        
        return false;
    };
};

/*

Run with:

    var validator = credentials_validator({
        "J. Doe": "P4ssword",
        "R. Wolf": "1234",
        "X. Ample": "wxyz#1"
    });

    validator("J. Doe", "P4ssword"); // true
    validator("R. Wolf", "123"); // false

*/
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the difficulty of this challenge is too low. Couldn't sandbox it for obvious reasons :p

Comment: Suggested test case: `var validator = credentials_validator(Object.create(null));`. Not sure if this is intended to be a valid input or not but the existing answer doesn't work for it.

Comment: @Etheryte I didn't mention this in the question because I didn't think about it, but assume the property names and values are within reason. The credentials object will just be ordinary names and passwords, not `{}` or `null` or `{ "isNaN": () => true }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> username = `'toString'`, password = `{}.toString`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVPPS8MwFL73r3iLh6YwC1NPjgqCXjwNFRREJGvT2ZEm5SVdnWN/e026deu0PRpKoXnv@/E@XpdsxXSMWWHOpUp4Xa8YQow84dJkTOiPFRNZwoxCiIB2CgFEN7DxwJ4sBWrWBVdpFwmjKAKi5kseGxI0je6YT1QVSF7Bs4XcIyqkxO/gfMhLbWDOgUlo4dMG37xSa4U6l6XmKFnOIZNd3aNUv6@3FvcOUa/DQZczpnWlMNGQszVI1ZjcwTVYV74shfBPzCI3JUqgreYYij1JJ79fXtuO/7V3sNiqj@hQoKfa@5FSW@EDVMNpH6bvozRY9jH@FdxOPft4bgnsfHYxXY7kIYQ7xck1kNnVToWM3f1jCC9KpK4wubi82l2@hnCbF6Jpr77W32cT4jgdZXfje/8EakVtil6spFaCh0It6LHoG/VkMJMLfwybbdh@BcG0rn8A)

Note: Due to a certain username pointed out by Wezl in the comments, this answer is not valid for the current challenge.

### Why this works:

> Among other properties, [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is inherited from `Object.prototype`, even if it wasn't a part of the object literal given to the validator. Since any object inherits the same function `{}.toString` is the same as the `toString` of the credentials object.

Comment: Well that was fast :p

Comment: What about `var v = credentials_validator({ "toString": "purple" }); v("toString", {}.toString)`?

Comment: @Wezl Good point, let me see if I can find another way.

Comment: @Wezl Unfortunately, I can't find a way to get around that. :(

Comment: `valueOf` is a shorter crack :-p

Comment: "this answer is not valid for the current challenge" -- Isn't this the one that was intended by the OP?

Comment: @Jonah It was, but they haven't restricted the usernames so that `toString` won't be allowed as a username.

Comment: @Wezl You may still define your own `Object.prototype` methods using a newly created `Symbol` to make sure no such username may ever exist. But I'm not sure if define some newly created attributes is allowed here.

Comment: That's why you should use `new Map()` as map not `({})` as map in JavaScript. If you are running on a quite old platform without `Map` support, try `Object.create(null)` or even `users = {}; users.__proto__ = null`.